# What does "との" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: usage

Unfortunately the sentence was written in romaji so i'm not sure if との is supposed to be written in hiragana or if its written in kanji but the sentence goes like this (the translation is also taken from the example) :

Person A: どこが違うと思いますか？
What do you think is different?

Person B: 日本人***との***違いですか？
Different from Japanese people?

Tried searching Jisho but couldn't find anything that would fit the meaning of the translation.

Comment: It seems like your question has been asked and answered before. Please let us know if this answers your question.

Comment: It did help clear things up, thank you.